# Play/Pause/Prev/Fwd buttons not working

Tags: macos, itunes, mac, keyboard, imac

**What I have:** macOS 10.10.2(Yosemite) on an iMac mid-2011 + original wireless keyboard.

Suddenly, buttons for controlling iTunes (they are located on <kbd>F7</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> buttons) stopped working. Meanwhile, other buttons (volume, brightness, launchpad, etc.) still work.

The keys work in other applications but not with iTunes.

Where should I look to fix this? Notice, the issue happened before updating to OS X Yosemite.

Comment: but they work with other applications?

Comment: Yes, the keys work actually. But not with itunes.

Comment: Did you try to cycle the "Use all F1..F12" in keyboard preferences On/Off

Comment: @Buscar웃 this option works as it should (on/off Fn+F combination) for all keys (volume, brightness, etc.) except iTunes.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution that doesn't involve chrome?  I have this issue but chrome does not appear to be at fault.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found this to solve the problem for me, thanks to [Major Hayden](https://major.io/2014/07/30/playpause-button-stopped-working-in-os-x-mavericks/)!

...check your keyboard shortcuts in Chrome:

- Choose Preferences in the Chrome menu in the menu bar
- Click Extensions in the left sidebar
- Scroll all the way to the bottom of the page
- Click Keyboard Shortcuts
- Look at the key bindings in the Google Play Music section
- Remove them all by by pressing the 'X' icon next to them.

Comment: This worked. But after a few days, the problem persists even though the shortcuts have been removed from Chrome. If I click in the textbox to add a shortcut, then the keys magically work. Has anyone else seen this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem but instead of Google Music it was Plex in Chrome that was causing the issues, solved the same way, going to Chrome > Extensions > Keyboard shortcuts > clicking x next to the Plex shortcuts.